# Want to set 'src' of script to my IP-Won't load in Safari or Chrome. Relative link asp.netmvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a **script** that links to the server I am hosting *(IP can change)* usually I would just use for links:

```
 var url ='http://' + window.location.hostname + 'end of url';
```

But in this case it isnt appearing to be so easy.

I have tried: (1)

```
$('#scriptid').attr('src', url);
```

as well as: (2)

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#insert").append( script );
```

Now case (2) works loads the script runs the script. But when at the end of my script it hits the 'write data' it decides to replace the entire page with just the data.

Any idea on how I can do this?

---

**Note:** I am using plain html not ASP. With ASP backend that is just the way it has to be.

Ok it now is

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

C#

```
router.AddAsyncRoute("myscript.js"......
```

It workes in IE & FF. But I get blank pages in Chrome & Safari. I am using document.write to write a script onto my page.

Any ideas why Chrome & Safari don't like this?

I am so far assuming that in Crhome & Safari it takes longer to run the script therefore launching the document.write after the DOM has loaded therefore replacing the page with a blank one.

Any ideas how I can get around this?
I am not to sure how to implement an appenChild in this case as the script is changing constantly with live data. So every refresh it will generally have changed some...

---

**So setting the Route actually does work perfectly fine..
I was having issues with loading it not because of my document.write *yes i know its nasty* but because Skype was hogging port 80 but only for Safari and Chrome because I had been using FF & IE before skype started.** So a simple disable of letting skype have port 80 in connection options and the

```
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

&

```
router.AddAsyncRoute("myscript.js"......
```

Work perfectly fine ^^

So the question still remains as I would still like to find out (if possible) how to set the 'src' tag of  a script to a variable or so?

Comment: Are you using `document.write` in the script you're loading? That's a big no-no after the (XHTML) DOM is complete. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

Comment: That could be a problem any work arounds?

Comment: No work arounds necessary, use proper DOM functions to manipulate. (`document.createElement` and `node.appendChild` etc.)

Comment: jQuery has a convenience function for loading scripts: `$.getScript(url)`. This won't solve your problem (you cannot do `document.write` after the page has loaded, no matter how you run the script) but looks nicer than manually creating script elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use absolute paths (domain name, IP). Just use the relative path to your script and you're good. Then you won't have to do any of this replacing etc. For instance if your script is called my_script.js don't use `src="http://...my_script.js"` use `src="my_script.js"`.

Comment: I see you're getting the URL of the same page, so the script seems to be local. Could you please explain some more ?